# SQL / PHP Calculator

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Im trying to make a little calculator with input given by a person, multiplying and adding these answers with some variables declared in php. But I can't get it to work properly.

What is wrong with this script? The writing to database part from the form works correctly. But when it directs to the output screen, the calculations don't really work.

```
mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "DM3") or die (MySQL_error());
mysql_select_db("calculator");

$order = "INSERT INTO calculator (nineholes , eightteenholes , hcp , club , academy , locker , rainflex ) VALUES ('$_POST[nineholes]','$_POST[eightteenholes]','$_POST[hcp]','$_POST[club]','$_POST[academy]','$_POST[locker]','$_POST[rainflex]') " ;
$result = mysql_query($order);  

//*Deze waarden kun je vrij veranderen
$brons = 44.00 ;
$zilver = 129.00 ;
$goud = 265.00 ;
$platinum = 599.00 ;

$greenfeebrons = 25.00 ;
$greenfeezilver = 17.50 ;
$greenfeegoud = 12.50 ;
greenfeeplatinum = 5.00 ;

$hcpx = 25.00 ;
$clubx = 65.00 ;
$academyx = 65.00 ;
$lockerx = 85.00 ;
$rainflexx = 45.00 ;

$allinx = 0.00 ;
$allinplatinumx = 0.00 ;

//*Deze waarden kun je niet veranderen

$nineholes = mysql_query('SELECT nineholes FROM calculator') ;
$eightteenholes = mysql_query('SELECT eightteenholes FROM calculator') ;
$hcp = mysql_query('SELECT hcp FROM calculator') ;
$club = mysql_query('SELECT club FROM calculator') ;
$academy = mysql_query('SELECT academy FROM calculator') ;
$locker = mysql_query('SELECT locker FROM calculator') ;
$rainflex = mysql_query('SELECT rainflex FROM calculator') ;
$allin = '0' ;
$allinplatinum = '0' ;


// Total
$bronstotaal =      $brons + (($nineholes / 4) * $greenfeebrons ) + (($eightteenholes / 5) * $greenfeebrons ) + (( $hcp / 6 ) * $hcpx ) +  (( $club / 7 ) * $clubx )  + (( $academy / 8 ) * $academyx) + (( $locker / 9 ) * $lockerx) + (( $rainflex / 10 ) * $rainflexx) + $allin + $allinplatinum;
$zilvertotaal =     $zilver + (($nineholes / 4)  * $greenfeezilver ) + (($eightteenholes / 5) * $greenfeezilver ) + (( $hcp / 6 ) * $hcpx ) +  (( $club / 7 ) * $clubx )  + (( $academy / 8 ) * $academyx) + (( $locker / 9 ) * $lockerx) + (( $rainflex / 10 ) * $rainflexx) + $allin + $allinplatinum;
$goudtotaal =       $goud + (($nineholes / 4)  * $greenfeegoud ) + (($eightteenholes / 5) * $greenfeegoud ) + (( $hcp / 6 ) * $hcpx ) +  (( $club / 7 ) * $clubx )  + (( $academy / 8 ) * $academyx) + (( $locker / 9 ) * $lockerx) + (( $rainflex / 10 ) * $rainflexx) + $allin + $allinplatinum;
$platinumtotaal =   $platinum + (($nineholes / 4)  * $greenfeeplatinum ) + (($eightteenholes / 5) * $greenfeeplatinum ) + (( $hcp / 6 ) * $hcpx ) +  (( $club / 7 ) * $clubx )  + (( $academy / 8 ) * $academyx) + (( $locker / 9 ) * $lockerx) + (( $rainflex / 10 ) * $rainflexx) + $allin + $allinplatinum;

if($result)
{
    echo ("<br> <u><b>Totaal:</b></u> <br>") ;
    echo ($bronstotaal) . "<br>" ;
    echo ($zilvertotaal) . "<br>" ;
    echo ($goudtotaal) . "<br>" ;
    echo ($platinumtotaal) . "<br>" ;
} 
else
{
    echo("<br>U heeft niet alles goed ingevuld");
}
```

Comment: mysql_query returns a **mysql result** not an int

Comment: Firstly you are missing a `$` at `greenfeeplatinum`, secondly you should fetch your results after the query.

Comment: A side note: [`mysql_*` is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), use `MySQLi` or `PDO` and _prepared statement / variable binding_.

Answer (score 1):

i recommended you to use mysqli btw:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM calculator') ;

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $nineholes = $row['nineholes'];
    $eightteenholes = $row['eightteenholes'];
    $hcp =  $row['hcp'];
    $club = $row['club'];
    //.
    //.
    //.
    //and so on
}
```

so you only need one Select and not so many ;)

Comment: would be nice if you vote for your prefered answer and mark it as the answer for your question ;)

Comment: Ah.. As you may notice I'm new to your ways :) // Edit: I cant vote you since I have no reputation :P

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query returns a resource after succesful execution of the query not a value,u need to fetch it.[Read here](https://www.php.net/mysql_query)

so replace all like the below:

```
$nineholes = mysql_query('SELECT nineholes FROM calculator') ;
```

with

```
$nineholes = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT nineholes FROM calculator'),0) ;
```

OR

better use the method which **Igoel** mentioned,that is more optimized way.

also as mentioned in the above comments you are missing a **$** at **greenfeeplatinum**

****Dont use mysql_* as they are deprecated.**

Answer (score 0):

Errors in your script:

1. Missing a $ at greenfeeplatinum
2. After running query as mysql_query, you have to fetch the values as

   ```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($nineholes))
   {
       $nine_hole = $row['nineholes'];
   }
   ```

   1. You can fetch all columns in a single query like

      SELECT * FROM calculator